# How to make 2D lighting in JavaScript

Tags: 2d, javascript, lighting, html-canvas, lightmap

I am making a recreation of the 2D voxel game Terraria in JavaScript. Like most sandbox games, Terraria has lighting, but because I am using JavaScript, performance is going to be an issue.

I have thought of a few ways I might do this:

One idea I have is to create a brightness map that stores a brightness value between 0 and 1 for each *corner* of a block, then draws a [gradient](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_gradients.asp) on top of each block based on those values. But you already know this will take too long to render.

Another idea I have, is to draw the whole thing black, then draw partially transparent circles of colors over that. This would allow me to have colored lights. But I don't want to code an entire lighting system that may also take too long to render.

What are some of the concepts used by most games to create 2D lighting effects, and which are the fastest?

I have seen [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/152559/achieving-2d-lighting-for-terraria-like-game) question but it doesn't actually describe how to make the lightmap.

Comment: Have you considered doing any of this work on the GPU via WebGL?

Comment: @DMGregory Am I able to use WebGL for 2D graphics? Though even if I am, I don't know anything about WebGL.

Comment: Hint: even 3D gets drawn to a 2D screen, so all graphics are 2D in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at ray casting.

The simplest approach is to cast rays from the center, which gives a reasonable approximate answer:

[image: simple ray casting]

A more advanced & precise version would only at angles where the walls begin or end:

[image: advanced ray casting]

The above examples were taken from [this tutorial on 2D visibility](https://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/) from Red Blob Games.

Best performance will be achieved with WebGL.
In my implementation I am doing all the calculations on the CPU and then drawing the shape with FAN mode and then rendering a circular gradient where shadows are cutoff.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for reviving the question, I know its already answered, but I came up with my own solution that does require an offscreen canvas, but it is pretty fast.

(WASD to move camera, scroll wheel for zooming, click and drag on walls to move them, press space to create polygon vertex, press enter to create the polygon.)

(check out the calculateLighting function for the main light code.)

Working Example:

```js
/**
 * @type { HTMLCanvasElement }
 */
var scene = document.getElementById("scene");
var ctx = scene.getContext("2d");

var vWidth = window.innerWidth;
var vHeight = window.innerHeight;

var targetFPS = 60;

var lastTimestamp = performance.now();
var fps = 1000;

var displayFPS = 1000;

function calculateFPS() {
    var delta = (performance.now() - lastTimestamp) / 1000;
    lastTimestamp = performance.now();
    fps = Math.trunc(1 / delta);
}

var friction = 0.8;
var worldScale = 1;
var zoomingDampener = 0.98;

var keysDown = [];

var mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    down: false,
    rightdown: false
}

var polyPoints = [];

var updateLoop;
var updateFPS;

function resizeCanvas() {
    vWidth = window.innerWidth;
    vHeight = window.innerHeight;
    scene.width = vWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
    scene.height = vHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;

    // tWidth = window.innerWidth;
    // tHeight = window.innerHeight;
    // scene.width = tWidth;
    // scene.height = tHeight;
}

resizeCanvas();

function random(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function clamp(min, max, value) {
    if (value < min) {
        return min;
    }

    if (value > max) {
        return max;
    }

    return value;
}

function lerp(start, end, t) {
    return start + (end - start) * clamp(0, 1, t);
}

function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

function radiansToDegrees(radians) {
    return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
}

function snapNumberToGrid(number, gridSize) {
    return Math.floor(number / gridSize) * gridSize;
}

function getCenterOfPolygon(vertices) {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        x += vertices[i].x;
        y += vertices[i].y;
    }
    return {
        x: x / vertices.length,
        y: y / vertices.length
    };
}

function rectangleToRectangleCollisionDetection(obj1, obj2) {
    if (obj1.x + obj1.width > obj2.x && obj1.x < obj2.x + obj2.width &&
        obj1.y + obj1.height > obj2.y && obj1.y < obj2.y + obj2.height) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function rectangleToRectangleCollisionResolution(obj1, obj2) {
    var vx = ((obj2.x + (obj2.width / 2)) - (obj1.x + (obj1.width / 2)));
    var vy = ((obj2.y + (obj2.height / 2)) - (obj1.y + (obj1.height / 2)));

    var dir = Math.atan2(vy, vx);

    if (Math.abs(vx / obj2.width) > Math.abs(vy / obj2.height)) {
        if (vx > 0) {
            obj1.x = obj2.x - obj1.width;
        } else {
            obj1.x = obj2.x + obj2.width;
        }
    } else {
        if (vy > 0) {
            obj1.y = obj2.y - obj1.height;
        } else {
            obj1.y = obj2.y + obj2.height;
        }
    }
}

function pointToRectangleCollisionDetection(obj1, obj2) {
    if (obj1.x > obj2.x && obj1.x < obj2.x + obj2.width &&
        obj1.y > obj2.y && obj1.y < obj2.y + obj2.height) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function rectangleToCircleCollisionDetection(rectangle, circle) {
    var testX = circle.x;
    var testY = circle.y;

    if (circle.x < rectangle.x) {
        testX = rectangle.x;
    } else if (circle.x > rectangle.x + rectangle.width) {
        testX = rectangle.x + rectangle.width;
    }

    if (circle.y < rectangle.y) {
        testY = rectangle.y;
    } else if (circle.y > rectangle.y + rectangle.height) {
        testY = rectangle.y + rectangle.height;
    }

    var distX = circle.x - testX;
    var distY = circle.y - testY;
    var distance = Math.sqrt((distX * distX) + (distY * distY));

    if (distance <= circle.radius) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function circleToCircleCollisionDetection(obj1, obj2) {
    var dx = obj2.x - obj1.x;
    var dy = obj2.y - obj1.y;
    var distance = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));

    if (distance <= obj1.radius + obj2.radius) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function pointToCircleCollisionDetection(point, circle) {
    var dx = point.x - circle.x;
    var dy = point.y - circle.y;
    var distance = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));

    if (distance <= circle.radius) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function pointToLineCollisionDetection(point, line) {
    var d1 = Math.sqrt((point.x - line.x1) * (point.x - line.x1) + (point.y - line.y1) * (point.y - line.y1));
    var d2 = Math.sqrt((point.x - line.x2) * (point.x - line.x2) + (point.y - line.y2) * (point.y - line.y2));

    var lineLen = Math.sqrt((line.x1 - line.x2) * (line.x1 - line.x2) + (line.y1 - line.y2) * (line.y1 - line.y2));

    var buffer = 0.2;

    if (d1 + d2 >= lineLen - buffer && d1 + d2 <= lineLen + buffer) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function pointToPolygonCollisionDetection(point, vertices) {
    var collision = false;

    for (var i = 0, j = vertices.length - 1; i < vertices.length; j = i++) {
        var xi = vertices[i].x, yi = vertices[i].y;
        var xj = vertices[j].x, yj = vertices[j].y;

        var intersect = ((yi > point.y) !== (yj > point.y)) &&
            (point.x < (xj - xi) * (point.y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);

        if (intersect) {
            collision = !collision;
        }
    }

    return collision;
}

class Vertex2D {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class Light {
    constructor(x, y, radius, color, intensity, isStatic = false) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
        this.intensity = intensity;
        this.static = isStatic;
        this.computeLighting = true;
        this.staticRays = [];
    }
}

class Wall {
    constructor(x, y, width, height, color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
    }
}

class WallCircle {
    constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
    }
}

class WallPoly {
    constructor(vertices = [], color) {
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.color = color;
    }
}

function calculateLighting(lights, walls) {
    // Light Calculation
    ctx.save();
    
    // Check if light is in wall
    for (var light of lights) {
        var continueLoop = false;

        for (var wall of walls) {
            if (wall instanceof WallCircle) {
                if (pointToCircleCollisionDetection(light, wall)) {
                    continueLoop = true;
                    break;
                }
            } else if (wall instanceof WallPoly) {
                if (pointToPolygonCollisionDetection(light, wall.vertices)) {
                    continueLoop = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (continueLoop == true) {
            continue;
        }

        // var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(light.x, light.y, 0, light.x, light.y, light.radius);
        // grad.addColorStop(0, light.color);
        // grad.addColorStop(1, "transparent");

        // Create array that stores all of the shadow quads for the light

        var allQuads = [];


        // Calculate all shadow quads for each wall and add them to the allQuads array
        for (var wall of walls) {
            if (wall instanceof WallPoly) {
                for (var i = 0; i < wall.vertices.length; i++) {
                    var vertex1 = wall.vertices[i];
                    var otherIndex = (i + 1) % wall.vertices.length;
                    var vertex2 = wall.vertices[otherIndex];

                    var quad = [];

                    var v1endv = Math.atan2(vertex1.y - light.y, vertex1.x - light.x);
                    var v2endv = Math.atan2(vertex2.y - light.y, vertex2.x - light.x);

                    quad.push(vertex1);

                    quad.push(new Vertex2D(vertex1.x + (Math.cos(v1endv) * light.radius * 50), vertex1.y + (Math.sin(v1endv) * light.radius * 50)));

                    quad.push(new Vertex2D(vertex2.x + (Math.cos(v2endv) * light.radius * 50), vertex2.y + (Math.sin(v2endv) * light.radius * 50)));

                    quad.push(vertex2);

                    allQuads.push(quad);
                }
            }
        }


        // Draw the lights with shadow quads
        var tmpCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var tmpCtx = tmpCanvas.getContext("2d");

        tmpCanvas.width = vWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
        tmpCanvas.height = vHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;

        // tmpCtx.scale(scale, scale);
        tmpCtx.scale(window.devicePixelRatio, window.devicePixelRatio);
        tmpCtx.scale(worldScale, worldScale);
        tmpCtx.translate(-(camera.x - (vWidth / (worldScale * 2))), -(camera.y - (vHeight / (worldScale * 2))));

        var grad = tmpCtx.createRadialGradient(light.x, light.y, 0, light.x, light.y, light.radius);
        grad.addColorStop(0, light.color);
        grad.addColorStop(1, "transparent");

        tmpCtx.save();
        tmpCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";

        tmpCtx.fillStyle = grad;
        tmpCtx.beginPath();
        tmpCtx.arc(light.x, light.y, light.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        tmpCtx.fill();
        tmpCtx.closePath();
        tmpCtx.restore();

        tmpCtx.save();
        tmpCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
        for (var i = 0; i < allQuads.length; i++) {
            var cQuad = allQuads[i];
            tmpCtx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
            tmpCtx.beginPath();
            tmpCtx.moveTo(cQuad[0].x, cQuad[0].y);
            for (var j = 1; j < cQuad.length; j++) {
                tmpCtx.lineTo(cQuad[j].x, cQuad[j].y);
            }
            tmpCtx.closePath();
            tmpCtx.fill();
        }
        tmpCtx.restore();


        // Draw the light to the main canvas
        ctx.save();
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
        ctx.drawImage(tmpCanvas, camera.x - (vWidth / 2) / worldScale, camera.y - (vHeight / 2) / worldScale, vWidth / worldScale, vHeight / worldScale);
        ctx.restore();
    }
    ctx.restore();
}

var walls = [];

function createShapeObj(x, y, radiusX, radiusY, sides, color, rotation = 0) {
    rotation = degreesToRadians(rotation);
    var shape = new WallPoly([], color);
    sides = Math.round(sides);
    var increment = 2 * Math.PI / sides;
    var currentSide = 0;
    // shape.vertices.push(new Vertex2D(x + (Math.cos(currentSide + rotation) * radiusX), y + (Math.sin(currentSide + rotation) * radiusY)));
    for (var i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
        currentSide += increment;
        shape.vertices.push(new Vertex2D(x + (Math.cos(currentSide + rotation) * radiusX), y + (Math.sin(currentSide + rotation) * radiusY)));
    }
    
    return shape;
}

function createRectangle(x, y, width, height, color) {
    var vertices = [
        new Vertex2D(x, y),
        new Vertex2D(x + width, y),
        new Vertex2D(x + width, y + height),
        new Vertex2D(x, y + height)
    ];

    walls.push(new WallPoly(vertices, color));
}

function drawShape(x, y, radiusX, radiusY, sides, color, rotation = 0) {
    sides = Math.round(sides);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    var increment = 2 * Math.PI / sides;
    var currentSide = 0;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x + (Math.cos(currentSide + rotation) * radiusX), y + (Math.sin(currentSide + rotation) * radiusY));
    for (var i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
        currentSide += increment;
        ctx.lineTo(x + (Math.cos(currentSide + rotation) * radiusX), y + (Math.sin(currentSide + rotation) * radiusY));
    }
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
}

function createShape(x, y, radiusX, radiusY, sides, color, rotation = 0) {
    rotation = degreesToRadians(rotation);
    var shape = new WallPoly([], color);
    sides = Math.round(sides);
    var increment = 2 * Math.PI / sides;
    var currentSide = 0;
    // shape.vertices.push(new Vertex2D(x + (Math.cos(currentSide + rotation) * radiusX), y + (Math.sin(currentSide + rotation) * radiusY)));
    for (var i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
        currentSide += increment;
        shape.vertices.push(new Vertex2D(x + (Math.cos(currentSide + rotation) * radiusX), y + (Math.sin(currentSide + rotation) * radiusY)));
    }

    walls.push(shape);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        createRectangle(random(-vWidth / 2, vWidth / 2), random(-vHeight / 2, vHeight / 2), 50, 50, "#808080");
}

var lights = [
    new Light(-128, 0, 512, "#00cc40", 1),
    new Light(128, 0, 512, "#0080ff", 1)
    // new Light(0, 64, 256, "#0000ff", 1)
    // new Light(200, 200, 256, "#801020", 1)
];

var theta = 0;

var selectedWall = null;

createShape(0, 0, 32, 32, 6, "#0080ff", 0);

class Camera {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.velX = 0;
        this.velY = 0;
        this.acceleration = 1;
    }
}

var camera = new Camera(0, 0);

function main() {
    calculateFPS();

    if (worldScale <= 0) {
        worldScale = 0;
    }

    theta += 0.05;

    if (mouse.down == true) {
        if (selectedWall != null) {
            if (selectedWall instanceof Wall) {
                // selectedWall.x += e.movementX / worldScale;
                // selectedWall.y += e.movementY / worldScale;

                // selectedWall.x = mouse.x - (selectedWall.width / 2);
                // selectedWall.y = mouse.y - (selectedWall.height / 2);

                selectedWall.x = lerp(selectedWall.x, mouse.x - (selectedWall.width / 2), 0.2);
                selectedWall.y = lerp(selectedWall.y, mouse.y - (selectedWall.height / 2), 0.2);
            } else if (selectedWall instanceof WallCircle) {
                // selectedWall.x = e.movementX / worldScale;
                // selectedWall.y = e.movementY / worldScale;

                // selectedWall.x = mouse.x;
                // selectedWall.y = mouse.y;

                selectedWall.x = lerp(selectedWall.x, mouse.x, 0.2);
                selectedWall.y = lerp(selectedWall.y, mouse.y, 0.2);
            } else if (selectedWall instanceof WallPoly) {
                var center = getCenterOfPolygon(selectedWall.vertices);
                for (var i = 0; i < selectedWall.vertices.length; i++) {
                    var vert = selectedWall.vertices[i];

                    var offsetX = vert.x - center.x;
                    var offsetY = vert.y - center.y;

                    // vert.x += e.movementX / worldScale;
                    // vert.y += e.movementY / worldScale;

                    // vert.x = mouse.x + offsetX;
                    // vert.y = mouse.y + offsetY;

                    vert.x = lerp(vert.x, mouse.x + offsetX, 0.2);
                    vert.y = lerp(vert.y, mouse.y + offsetY, 0.2);
                }
            } else if (selectedWall instanceof Light) {
                // selectedWall.x = mouse.x;
                // selectedWall.y = mouse.y;

                selectedWall.x = lerp(selectedWall.x, mouse.x, 0.2);
                selectedWall.y = lerp(selectedWall.y, mouse.y, 0.2);
            }
        }
    }

    if (keysDown["w"]) {
        camera.velY -= camera.acceleration;
    }

    if (keysDown["a"]) {
        camera.velX -= camera.acceleration;
    }

    if (keysDown["s"]) {
        camera.velY += camera.acceleration;
    }

    if (keysDown["d"]) {
        camera.velX += camera.acceleration;
    }

    camera.velX *= friction;
    camera.velY *= friction;

    camera.x += camera.velX;
    camera.y += camera.velY;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.scale(window.devicePixelRatio, window.devicePixelRatio);

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, vWidth, vHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#101520";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, vWidth, vHeight);

    ctx.scale(worldScale, worldScale);
    ctx.translate(-(camera.x - (vWidth / (worldScale * 2))), -(camera.y - (vHeight / (worldScale * 2))));

    for (var wall of walls) {
        ctx.fillStyle = wall.color;
        if (wall instanceof Wall) {
            ctx.fillRect(wall.x, wall.y, wall.width, wall.height);
        } else if (wall instanceof WallCircle) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(wall.x, wall.y, wall.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        } else if (wall instanceof WallPoly) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(wall.vertices[0].x, wall.vertices[0].y);
            for (var i = 1; i < wall.vertices.length; i++) {
                ctx.lineTo(wall.vertices[i].x, wall.vertices[i].y);
            }
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }

    calculateLighting(lights, walls);

    if (polyPoints.length > 0) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(polyPoints[0].x, polyPoints[0].y);

        for (var i = 1; i < polyPoints.length; i++) {
            var point = polyPoints[i];

            ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }

        ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    ctx.restore();

    ctx.save();
    ctx.scale(window.devicePixelRatio, window.devicePixelRatio);
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.font = " 14px arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    ctx.fillText(`FPS: ${displayFPS}`, 5, 5);
    ctx.restore();

    // requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

updateLoop = setInterval(main, 1000 / targetFPS);

updateFPS = setInterval(function () {
    displayFPS = fps;
}, 1000);

// main();

window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    keysDown[e.key] = true;

    if (e.key === " ") {
        polyPoints.push(new Vertex2D(mouse.x, mouse.y));
    }
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    keysDown[e.key] = false;

    if (e.key === "Enter" && polyPoints.length > 1) {
        walls.push(new WallPoly(polyPoints, "#208040"));
        polyPoints = [];
    }
});

window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);

window.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    if (e.button === 0) {
        mouse.down = true;
    } else if (e.button === 2) {
        mouse.rightdown = true;
    }

    if (selectedWall == null) {
        var lightPoints = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < lights.length; i++) {
            var light = lights[i];
            lightPoints.push(light);
        }

        var rt = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < lightPoints.length; i++) {
            var lp = lightPoints[i];

            if (pointToCircleCollisionDetection(mouse, { x: lp.x, y: lp.y, radius: 25 }) == true) {
                selectedWall = lp;
                rt = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (rt == true) {
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < walls.length; i++) {
            var wall = walls[i];

            if (wall instanceof Wall) {
                if (pointToRectangleCollisionDetection(mouse, wall)) {
                    selectedWall = wall;
                    break;
                }
            } else if (wall instanceof WallCircle) {
                if (pointToCircleCollisionDetection(mouse, wall)) {
                    selectedWall = wall;
                    break;
                }
            } else if (wall instanceof WallPoly) {
                if (pointToPolygonCollisionDetection(mouse, wall.vertices)) {
                    selectedWall = wall;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

scene.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // polyPoints.push(new Vertex2D(mouse.x, mouse.y));
});

window.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
    selectedWall = null;
    mouse.down = false;
    mouse.rightdown = false;
});

window.addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
});

// scene.onclick = function () {
//     scene.requestPointerLock();
// }

window.onwheel = function (e) {
    if (event.wheelDelta) {
        if (event.wheelDelta > 0) {
            worldScale /= zoomingDampener;
            return -1;
        } else {
            worldScale *= zoomingDampener;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if (event.deltaY < 0) {
        worldScale /= zoomingDampener;
        return -1;
    } else {
        worldScale *= zoomingDampener;
        return 1;
    }
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    mouse.x = (e.clientX + (camera.x * worldScale) - (vWidth / 2)) / worldScale;
    mouse.y = (e.clientY + (camera.y * worldScale) - (vHeight / 2)) / worldScale;

    // lights[0].x = mouse.x;
    // lights[0].y = mouse.y;
});

window.onerror = function (ev) {
    alert(ev)
}
```

```css
:root {
    --light-samples: "100";
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    font-family: roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, system-ui;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    color: #ffffff;
  background: #000000;
}

canvas {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="scene"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```